# How does pythonw find zlib on a windows anaconda installation?

Tags: windows-7, python, anaconda

I have been using an Anaconda Python installation on this Win7 computer for several years, with the Spyder IDE.  Recently, I started to get pop-up warnings from pythonw that zlib was not installed, and that I should reinstall it.  A search for 'zlib' on drive C: turns up many copies of zlib.dll and zlib1.dll.

What does pythonw need, and how can I verify/repair/reinstall it?

PS. The issue with Pillow referred to in the comment looks very different to me.

PPS. Regarding the second comment, you are right, but I am just basically asking what it takes for python to find zlib normally, so I can check it.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733647/cant-install-pillow-for-python-3-x-in-windows-zlib-is-required) ?  It looks like the same problem to me.

Comment: *"Recently, I started to get pop-up warnings from pythonw that zlib was not installed, and that I should reinstall it."* - Unfortunately, this doesn't paint a very clear picture for me of what is actually happening. What are the actual steps you are taking when this error occurs and can you post a screenshot/transcription of the exact  error?